# Generate typescript defenition file per Vue 3 components using rollup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, rollup, rollupjs

The following rollup config generates this dist folder:

[image: dist]

rollup.config.js:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import filesize from "rollup-plugin-filesize";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "./index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      vue(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      filesize(),
    ],
    external: ["vue"],
  },
];
```

Well, I am using this config in React.js application too and it generates this dist folder:

[image: dist]

as you see it generates a definition file per React component.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "ESNext",
    
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@types",
      "./shims-vue.d.ts"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": ["./components", "./**/*.ts", "./**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: What does it say in your tsconfig.json? Do you have the [declaration option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) set?

Comment: @MoritzRingler Yes, it has already been set up.

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig.json to the question?